# How to split an MKV file into HLS segments of approximately 25MB each?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, hls

I'm reaching out to seek your help regarding the partitioning of an MKV file into HLS segments composed of TS files. I'm aiming to divide my portions into segments of maximum 25MB size, but it seems that something is not working as expected.

I've tried using the `hls_segment_size` option, but it is not yielding the desired results. Perhaps the keyframes in the video are too sparsely spaced, resulting in segments exceeding the desired size (even though I set a maximum segment size of 10MB, I ended up with segments of 30MB and more).

I would greatly appreciate your assistance and any suggestions or recommendations to overcome this issue.

Below is a sample of the command I've used:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries packet=pts_time,flags -of csv=print_section=0 video.mkv > output.txt
```

[Portion of output.txt](https://pastebin.com/zuDzdNiK)

This is my ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_size 10485760 -hls_segment_filename temp_folder_path/ffmpeg_output_filename_%06d.ts temp_folder_path/ffmpeg_output_filename.m3u8
```

Thank you in advance for your help!